# Flatten the data frame column of list containing nested dictionaries in a unique way shown

Tags: python, json, dataframe, dictionary, flatten

Flattening dataframe column of the list of nested dictionaries in a way shown below.

Guys, I'm new to python, but I'm trying really hard to achieve the goal but unfortunately unable to do so.

current Dataframe:

```
col1    col2
path1    [{sheetname1:{value11:length11,value12:length12,value13:length13...}},
          {sheetname2:{value21:length21,value22:lenth22,...}}]
```

resulting datafarme:

```
col1    col2          col3     col4
path1   sheetname1   value11     length11
path1   sheetname1   value12     length12
path1   sheetname1   value13     length13
...
...
...
path1   sheetname2  value21    length21
path1   sheetname2  value22    length22
...
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
data = []
for col1, row in zip(df["col1"], df["col2"]):
    for d in row:
        for k, v in d.items():
            for kk, vv in v.items():
                data.append({"col1": col1, "col2": k, "col3": kk, "col4": vv})

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
    col1        col2     col3      col4
0  path1  sheetname1  value11  length11
1  path1  sheetname1  value12  length12
2  path1  sheetname1  value13  length13
3  path1  sheetname2  value21  length21
4  path1  sheetname2  value22   lenth22
```

Comment: I love you, bro, you saved my life, sending tons of best wishes for you!!